# Floor division and modulo with negative number

Tags: python-3.x

```
print(-2//4)
```

The output is -1. I do not understand the logic. Why the negative modulo?

Comment: `(-2) ÷ 4` is `-1 remainder 2`. The remainder has to be between 0 (inclusive) and 4 (exclusive), so this is the only answer that works.

Answer (score 1):

`(-2) ÷ 4` gives `-1 remainder 2`.

The relation that has to be correct is that for integers `a` and `b`

```
a = (a//b) * b + (a%b)
```

In this case, `b` is 4, and the remainder `a%b` must be between 0 (inclusive) and 4 (exclusive). So the only values for `a//b` and `a%b` that work are

```
a//b = -1
a%b = 2
```

which gives

```
-2 = -1 * 4 + 2
a   a//b  b  a%b
```

---

TLDR

The precise value of `(-2) / 4` is `-0.5`. The greatest integer not greater than `-0.5` is `-1`.